# Sequence length in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

I have a dataframe in python that has a column like below:

```
Type   
 A        
 A 
 B
 B
 B
```

I want to add another column to my data frame according to the sequence of Type:

```
Type   Seq  
 A      1       
 A      2
 B      1
 B      2
 B      3
```

I was doing it in R with the following command:

```
setDT(df)[ , Seq := seq_len(.N), by = rleid(Type) ]
```

I am not sure how to do it python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit for updated question

```
df['seq'] = df.groupby('Type').cumcount() + 1
df
```

Output:

```
  Type  seq
0    A    1
1    A    2
2    B    1
3    B    2
4    B    3
```

---

Use `pd.factorize`:

```
import pandas as pd
df['seq'] = pd.factorize(df['Type'])[0] + 1
df
```

Output:

```
  Type  seq
0    A    1
1    A    1
2    B    2
3    B    2
4    B    2
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually made a mistake in my question that I edited now. I want the sequence be (1,2) and (1,2,3).

Comment: @user36729 Okay answer that too.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Series.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html),

```
df['seq'] = df['Type'].rank(method = 'dense').astype(int)

   Type seq
0   A   1
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   B   2
4   B   2
```

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas`

```
(df.Type!=df.Type.shift()).ne(0).cumsum()
Out[58]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: Type, dtype: int32
```

---

More info

```
v=c('A','A','B','B','B','A')
data.table::rleid(v)
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3


df 
  Type
0    A
1    A
2    B
3    B
4    B
5    A# assign a new  number in R data.table rleid
(df.Type!=df.Type.shift()).ne(0).cumsum()
Out[60]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3# check
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best way but try this:

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == A, 'Seq'] = 1
```

Similarly, for B:

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == B, 'Seq'] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A strange (and not recommended) way of doing it is to use the built-in `ord()` function to get the Unicode code-point of the character.

That is:

```
df['Seq'] = df['Type'].apply(lamba x: ord(x.lower())-96)
```

**A much better way of doing it is to change the type of the strings to categories:**

```
df['Seq'] = df['Type'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

You may have to increment the codes if you want different numbers.